# In shell, how do I test a return code recorded from $?

Tags: shell, exit-code

Silly sort of question, but...

I can exit if a command fails easily enough:

```
command || exit $?
```

If I want to interpose something between the command and the exit, I can test the return code vs 0, or just exit from a subshell:

```
command ; rc=$?
echo That command returned $rc
[ $rc -eq 0 ] || exit $rc
# or
( exit $rc ) || exit $rc
```

But I don't like test vs 0, because it makes 0=true explicit.

And while I like ( exit $rc ) because it avoids explicit 0, a subshell seems heavyweight and using exit twice seems redundant.

Is there some better alternative?

Comment: In the salme way you tried exit, you could use a bash function returning  its input, no ?

Comment: @LaurentG I could, but then I'd have to define that, so it wouldn't be a simple one liner.

Comment: its depends on the line length ... with some braces and semi-colons ... /o\

Comment: @LaurentG lol. I'll use a small font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quiiiite what I had in mind, but close enough for me because I generally only care about failure:

```
$ bash
bash-3.2$ false || exit $? $( echo worbly boo $? > /dev/tty )
worbly boo 1
exit
```

It short-cuts the `$( )` conveniently, so no subshell except in an error case.

It also handles failures within the `$( )` fairly elegantly:

```
bash-3.2$ false || exit $? $( ( foo ; echo $? ) > /dev/tty )
bash: foo: command not found
127
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a function to handle the fail case:

```
fail() { 
    echo failed with code $1;
    exit $1;
}
true || fail $?           # does nothing
false || fail $?          # outputs failed... and exits
```